# What will be the impact on throughput put value when i keep no. of threads=25 and ramp up period =1?

Tags: jmeter

And then changing the ramp up period to =2 and keep the no. of threads  to 25

Whether the throughput value should increase when increasing the ramp up period and keep no. of threads same. Please explain its confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to explain it by using Test plan with only Debug Sampler and Summary Report,

If ramp up period to = 1, **it can** produce **throughput = 25** requests/seconds

But if ramp up period to = 25, **it will always produce throughput = 1** requests/seconds

When ramp up > 1 it delays thread creation, in this case one thread every second

Answer (score 0):

According to [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

> **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>   The formula is: `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).`

So given you increase test duration by 1 second and sending the same amount of requests you should get **less** throughput given you increase ramp-up time and vice versa.

If response time of your application is less than 1 second my expectation is that you will get 2x times less throughput if the ramp-up is 2 seconds.

The actual throughput will strongly depend on your application response time and its reaction to increased load.

You might also be interested in [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second/)